# PHP how to open page1, redirect to page2 and show page1 in a div dom?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, redirect

I have many sub pages, there urls like `www.domain.com/sub/page1.php` `www.domain.com/sub/page2.php`... Now when I type there url in browser. they all redirect to `www.domain.com/sub/index.php`, and the current sub page will show in a div dom in the `index.php`.

My knowledge is very limited. I only know `jqeury.load` and  `php header Location`. but it is difficult redirect to `index.php` then tell `index.php`, which is the current sub-pages then do a `jqeury.load`.

**One more note**: Also should think `SEO`. maybe `jqeury.load` is bad for a search spider. maybe should use `hash` url.

So I ask for a help. is there anybody could give me some good suggestion? or simple worked examples?

Thanks.

Comment: how the redirection is done? via javascript? or Apache ModRewrite?

Comment: http://danwebb.net/2011/5/28/it-is-about-the-hashbangs

Comment: @ArtoAle, I tyied `header Location` but not success.so javascript? or Apache ModRewrite. All are well, just get the effection. Thanks.

Comment: If you are loading one page in another, would an iFrame not work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every PHP file (e.g `page1.php`) use this code:

```
<?php
if(!defined('INCLUDE')) {
    header('Location: index.php?site=' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); //Send the user to the index.php page
    die();
}
?>
Insert the content you want here...
```

And in the `index.php` file:

```
<?php
define('INCLUDE', true);
if(isset($_GET['site'])) {
    $site = $_GET['site'];
} else {
    $site = 'page100.php'; //Put the name of the default page if the user visits index.php here
}
?>
<html>
<head><!-- HEAD CONTENT HERE --></head>
<body>
<div><?php 
include($site); //Put the page requested into the div
?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: great method. one more question: if `page1.php` in a folder name `files`.(files is a sub folder in web root) how to write `header('Location:`?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: It would be `header('Location: ../index.php`. You can also use `header('Location: /sub/index.php` for files both in a subfolder (called `files`) and in the web root.